# How do i init a tuple property from a class in swift?

Tags: swift, tuples

I have this property in my class

```
var service = (String, Int, Bool)
```

and i need to use a constructor with init, so i have the next code

```
init()
{
  self.service(1) = "Fix PC"
  self.service(2) = 400
  self.service(3) = false
}
```

On every line of the init code i got the next message

> type of expression is ambiguous without more context

, how can i fix it?

I'm a student, recently using swift, still cant find a solution

Comment: How would you initialize a tulle that isn’t a stored property?

Comment: You probably meant `service.0`, `service.1`, `service.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not the way to assign a value to a tuple. You need to assign the tuple as a whole, you cannot assign its properties 1-by-1.

```
var service: (String, Int, Bool)

init() {
    service = ("Fix PC", 400, false)
}
```

Once the tuple is initialised, you can update its members 1-by-1, however your syntax was wrong, tuple member access is done using `.`, not `()`.

```
service.0 = "Fix Mac"
```

Also, you should only be using tuples as temporary storage, for your example, you should be using a custom type with 3 separate properties.

```
struct Service {
    let name: String
    let value: Int
    let bool: Bool
}

let service = Service(name: "Fix PC", value: 400, bool: false)
```

Comment: Thanks! I know they should be used as temporary storage, but it is for a school homework and they want us to use it like this

Comment: If this answers your question, please click the checkmark next to it (and maybe upvote it).